# Why does the CentOS 5.8 install give an error about CD-ROM drive when using HP ILO?

Tags: linux, centos, hp, ilo

CentOS 5.8

I'm trying to install CentOS 5.8 on the following system with the following specs:

- HP DL360e Gen8
- HP Dynamic Smart Array 8320i RAID Controller
- ILO 4 v1.05

I'm connecting the ISO to the server via a virtual disk using HP ILO4.

It initially seems to boot fine... I see lines like:

```
Loading vmlinuz........
Loading initrd.img...................
```

Followed by various bios messages....

Eventually I see the anaconda installer start and get the following message:

```
Loading SCSI driver
Loading usb-storage driver...
```

Followed by:

```
Loading SCSI driver
Loading ahci driver...
```

Then finally, I get:

```
CD Not Found

CentOS CD was not found in any of your CDROM drives.  Please insert the CentOS CD and press OK to retry.
```

If I select OK, it gives me the same error.

From what I can dig up, ILO essentially mounts the CD as a USB CD Drive to the system.  I'm wondering if for some reason a driver for facilitating this isn't available (although I'm still confused on how I could get this far).

On a side note, I don’t see this specific system (HP DL360e Gen8) listed on the RedHat hardware compatibility list (https://hardware.redhat.com/list.cgi?product=Red+Hat+Hardware+Certification&quicksearch=DL360)  There are a lot of DL360s but not this specific model…  I wonder if the hardware is different enough to not support it?  That being said, I do see RHEL 5.7 listed here: http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/os/certification.html?var1=DL360e%20Gen8 so perhaps it should work fine?

Comment: Moar info! ILO version (ILO2, ILO3, ILO4, LO100?), firmware and server model are helpful.

Comment: This isn't on a BL685 G7 is it? or any other AMD-based G7 is it? I know there's some big issues with 5.7 and these boxes, can't recall them all but I know we have a >=5.8 rule for those boxes.

Comment: @Chopper3 Sorry - I messed up on the version.  It's actually CentOS 5.8.

Comment: @ewwhite Good questions. I'll get specifics.

Comment: @MikeB also, which .ISO are you using, and how large is it?

Comment: @ewwhite It's a customized full-install CD preloaded with some other packages. I suppose that could be it too -- missing drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you're using a customized CD image for this. An easy test of the ILO or the driver support for this system is to download a standard CentOS DVD image or possibly a [rescue or Live CD](http://rescuecd.pld-linux.org/). Doing the latter will be quick and an easy way to test if the machine is capable of loading fully. Run the download and see if the system boots. If it does, your issue is the customized CentOS ISO image.

Given that HP is standard hardware with good support for Linux, its drivers are available in most distributions. The SCSI devices should be picked up without incident. The RAID controller uses the [HPSA](http://cciss.sourceforge.net/) driver on newer OS releases. Yours may end up using the [CCISS](http://cciss.sourceforge.net/) driver.

You should [upgrade the firmware of your ILO](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5249571&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D5249570%257CprodNameId%253D5249571%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-2c7ccf85f52d441b93fe665714%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) as well. The current version is 1.10, and includes a large number of fixes/enhancements. If you have a Windows workstation, you can download the [Windows ILO firmware package](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5249571&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D5249570%257CprodNameId%253D5249571%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-2c7ccf85f52d441b93fe665714%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken), extract and update the firmware through the ILO web page.

The same applies to the [newest system BIOS](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5249571&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D5249570%257CswItem%253DMTX-ced7e4a7e7f04ff79a8ace56c4%257CprodNameId%253D5249571%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CswLang%253D8%257Cmode%253D4%257Cidx%253D2%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

One more thing. Please make sure you don't have any USB storage connected to the system as you're trying this. That includes USB thumb drives, external hard drives, internal SD cards and anything else in that category.